# Parse.com User.get("column") only works for current user

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have an object called Group, which stores an array of Users (default Parse user) as a column. I am trying to list all of these users' display names (column called "displayName") in a certain group, but for some reason, when I try to use the .get function on a user in the retrieved array, it only gives me the information for the current user. I checked my permissions and ACL and it says for each user Public Read, and the User class has public read and write permissions. Here is the code I am using:

```
var groupObject = Parse.Object.extend("Group");
  var users = [];
  var groupQuery = new Parse.Query(groupObject);
  groupQuery.get(groupId,{
    success: function(group)
    {
      users = group.get("Users");
      for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++)
      {
        var user = users[i];
        console.log("display name: " + user.get("displayName") + "username: " + user.get("username") + "id: " + user.id);
      }
      doneCallback(users);
    },
    error: function(object, error)
    {
      errorCallback(error);
    }
  });
```

I am able to console.log all of their ids, and the query is successful, but the only thing I can use get("column") on is the current user (which is part of the group users array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use a **Relation** instead of an **Array** to store your users in the Group object. It will be way easier to add, remove, fetch and access your user objects via the relation. You also avoid some headache when the list of your users becomes large. Then you should be able to fetch all the users in any given group like this:

```
var groupObject = new Parse.Object("Group");
groupObject.set("objectId", yourGroupId);
var query = groupObject.relation("Users").query();

Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

query.find().then( function(users) {
    _.each(users, function(user) {
        console.log(user.get("displayName"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Using a relation fixed the issue and should save me resources in the long run.

Comment: No problem. Glad it was helpful